# Laravel - Integrity constraint violation when trying to create a product

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a product in the db but I'm just getting the error message -
-SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_type_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `products` (`product_type_id`, `product_name`, `fname`, `sname`, `price`, `pages`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, test, test, test, 15, 15, 2020-12-05 22:25:41, 2020-12-05 22:25:41)) -

I've tried changing the controller around so it would be like this

```
 $input = $request->all();
```

And also tried changing the post method but no success.

Controller -

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {    
        $product = new Product();
        $product->product_type_id = request('producttype');
        $product->product_name = request('title');
        $product->fname = request('fname');
        $product->sname = request('sname');
        $product->price = request('price');
        $product->pages = request('pages');
        
       $product->save();
       return redirect('/product');
    }
```

template-create.blade.php

```
<div class="grid-item">
     <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/product/create') }}">
     @csrf
    <h1>Create a product</h1>
    <select id="producttype" value="producttype" name="Product">
      <option value="1">Book</option>
      <option value="2">CD</option>
      <option value="3">Game</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="title" placeholder="Title">
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="fname" placeholder="First Name">
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="sname" name="sname" value="sname" placeholder="Surname / Band">
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="price" placeholder="Price">
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="pages" name="pages" value="pages" placeholder="Pages / Playlength / PEGI">
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Add new product</button>
    <form/>
</div>
```

Product model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
        protected $fillable = [
        'product_type_id',
        'product_name',
        'fname',
        'sname',
        'price',
        'pages',
    ];
    
    public function productType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ProductType', 'product_type_id');
    }
    
    public function outOfStock() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Web route

```
Route::post('/product/create', [ProductController::class, 'store']);
```

Any assistance on this problem would be amazing, as I've been stuck on this error for a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your Laravel codes, you expect to see `producttype` in your request and set it as `product_type_id`'s value of your Product.

But you're sending it as `Product` in HTML form.

Just Replace

```
<select id="producttype" value="producttype" name="Product">
```

with :

```
<select id="producttype" name="producttype">
```

:)

Comment: Also the `id` attribute seems to be useless in your form.